# Searching through incrementally increasing variable names and comparing them against a certain value in Java

Tags: java

I have multiple variables named label1, label2 etc. (all strings) and I was wondering if there was a way to iterate through all these variables (up to label9) to check them against a certain string "x" or "o". As of right now, all I can do is either have multiple if statements to check them, or put them all into an array and check them that way. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `Array` for this? instead of having `label1`,`label2` etc ?

Comment: The only reason is because these labels are actually JLabels for a GUI i'm building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbered variables mean you should actually use arrays or lists.
Then `label1` becomes `label[1]` or `label.get(1)` and you can iterate easily.

But if you really want to you could use reflection:

```
String label1 = "foo";
String label2 = "bar";
String label3 = "x";

private void printAll() {
    for (Field f : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (f.getName().matches("label[1-9]")) {
            try {
                String value = (String) f.get(this);
                if (value.equals("x")) {
                    System.out.println(f.getName() + " is x");
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/KQf9uO